# Simulation directory in Vivado

Tags: vivado

Can someone kindly explain me why in a Vivado project, under simulation, there is a directory called "Sim1"? If I create different testbeches, should I put each testbench in a different directory? What about if I create an other directory called "Sim2"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can define different simulation sets. Please open `Settings` in your `Project Manager` and choose the tab `Simulation`. You will find a field called `Simulation Set`. Use this to define another simulation set, for example `sim_2`. You can define different testbenches in your sets, so you can easily switch between different test cases.

Please see the following example:
I have a design with two different testbenches (in this case the testbenches are the same), and so I create two simulation sets.
[image]

Each set has his own testbench and his own waveform configuration file (containing the signals, the layout and the formatting of each signal).

You can change the set by right clicking the chosen set and clicking `Make Active`:
[image]

The set changes to `sim_1`. The testbench of `sim_1` is set as Top and the waveform configuration file is used for the simulation.

[image]

Note: Each set needs a top file, so Vivado will ask you for a top file when you switch to a set without a top file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! Just to be sure...so I can also create different testbenches in the same folder, the only advantage in create different directories is that then you can switch easily between them, is it right?

Comment: Yes, you can create different testbenches, but you can only set one as active. Another disadvantage is, that you (maybe) have two waveform configuration files, when you use two testbenches and both files are loaded, when you run the simulation (and one waveform might be empty, because the signals are missing).
A smarter solution would be to use different simulation sets and use each set for a different testbench. So you have a directory with your testbench and your waveform configuration file for your testbench - and you can easily switch between your test cases.

Comment: That's clear. but if I use different simulation sets, to define on which testbench I want to run the simulation I have just to set it as Top? Doing like this I should display only the related waveform, is it right?

Comment: Please check my updated explanation and ask if you have some more questions :)

Comment: I have successfully tried to create a new folder for the simulation (Sim2), but I have a problem. The file which should be set as top, can't be set. It is in the Source box, under Simulation Source, but it appears as Non-moduel Files. If I right click on it, the option Set as Top is not available. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with your problem? Do you use the `Add Sources` wizard to create the source?

Comment: Below you will find the screenshot

Comment: Is this file empty? It seems that Vivado mark it as `Non-module File` when the file doesn´t contain any data. I do the same steps than you and the file is marked as `Non-Module File` when it is empty and as a normal file when it contains code.

Comment: Yes, it was still empty. I will try to write some code and I will let you know if it works. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you were right, as soon as I added some code my new testbench was not under Non-module Files anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used Add Simulation File, then I have created the new directory and I have created the file auto_check_tb, which is under Non-Module Files